# string search in table with partial text and without all field names

Tags: postgresql, string-searching

I use postgresql database and the need is to return all the rows that contain a given string in any column of that table. And string could be like just half . For examaple search string can ve IT   and I should return record of ITALY .

my table is something like

[image: table]

currently using this query but it is not working for half text. and don't want to user fields name in   `IN` like (1st field ,2nd filed, 3rd filed ) is there something `*` like generic there ?

**currently using this**

```
select *
from the_table
where 'Italy' IN (name, native, place);
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a string consisting of what you want to match against, and test against that. It could be as simple as casting the whole row to text:

```
testdb=# create table t(userid integer, uname text, native text, place text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into t select 1, 'Richard', 'Italy', 'San Francisco';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 2, 'Elon', 'Europe', 'New York';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 3, 'John', 'Vietnam', 'Italy';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select t::text from t;
                 t                 
-----------------------------------
 (1,Richard,Italy,"San Francisco")
 (2,Elon,Europe,"New York")
 (3,John,Vietnam,Italy)
(3 rows)

testdb=# select * from t where t::text ~ 'It';
 userid |  uname  | native  |     place     
--------+---------+---------+---------------
      1 | Richard | Italy   | San Francisco
      3 | John    | Vietnam | Italy
(2 rows)
```

Or, if you want to ensure that commas in the search string don't cause it to match more than one column, or if you need to omit any of the columns, use `concat()` to separate the values with unprintable chars instead.

```
testdb=# select concat(uname, e'\x01', native, e'\x01', place) from t;
              concat               
-----------------------------------
 Richard\x01Italy\x01San Francisco
 Elon\x01Europe\x01New York
 John\x01Vietnam\x01Italy
(3 rows)

testdb=# select * from t where t::text ~ 'rd,It';
 userid |  uname  | native |     place     
--------+---------+--------+---------------
      1 | Richard | Italy  | San Francisco
(1 row)

testdb=# select * from t where concat(uname, e'\x01', native, e'\x01', place) ~ 'rd,It';
 userid | uname | native | place 
--------+-------+--------+-------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: why I can't use query like this ?  select *
from the_table
where 'Italy' IN (name, native, place);

Comment: Because, in your question, you state that want to be able to search for partial strings (`'It'` -> Italy). `'string_literal' IN (list, of, columns)` is only true if the string appears *as* one of the column values, not *in* one of the column values (as that would be a matching, rather than an equality, operation).